# Change ADO .NET Entity Framework connection string from SQL Server to localDB

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

So I used 'Reverse Engineer Code First' on a SQL Server database.  I am now wanting to point it at a localDB instance for automated testing of the consuming code.

I have the following connection string in my configuration:

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Server\Instance;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

How would I change this connection string (for placing in the app.config of the test project) so that I could create a localDB (mdf) in my test project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add in the "AttachDBFilename" property and set the Datasource to the connection string like so -

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyCatalogDb.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: This sort of worked. I had to declare a value for "|DataDirectory|" though.  Then I had a hard time making it create the file.  But, that is a different question I suppose.  Thanks!